# For loop isn't gathering all data on web scrape

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm making this web scrape for a project but it only returns one of the values i'm looking for instead of also running the other 18 elements in listings. It will return all the information on 1 house but i want the information on the other 18 houses also stored in the variables. Thanks very much.

'''

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
my_url = "https://www.daft.ie/ireland/property-for-sale/"

#open connection and grab webpage
uClient = uReq(my_url)
#store html in a variable
page_html = uClient.read() 
#close web connection
uClient.close()

#parse html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
print(soup)
#grabs listings house information
listings = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"FeaturedCardPropertyInformation__detailsContainer"})

for container in listings:
    #extracting price
    price= container.div.div.strong.text
    #location
    name_container = container.div.find("a", {"class":"PropertyInformationCommonStyles__addressCopy- 
    -link"}).text
    #house type
    house = container.div.find("div", {"class":"QuickPropertyDetails__propertyType"}).text
    #number of bathrooms
    bath_num = container.div.find("div", {"class":"QuickPropertyDetails__iconCopy-- 
    WithBorder"}).text
    #number of bedrooms
    bed_num = container.div.find("div", {"class":"QuickPropertyDetails__iconCopy"}).text
```

'''

Comment: Though you are iterating over the collection (loop), you always overwriting on same set of scalar variables such as price, house, etc. You may need to use some collection type to capture all the values which are inferred within loop.

Comment: @Nair As in create a list then append them to that list? Apologies i'm quite weak at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a blank list before `for` loop and append all the variable in every iteration to store all data in a single list.

Your code will look as follows:

```
data = []

for container in listings:
    # extracting price
    price = container.div.div.strong.text
    # location
    name_container = container.div.find("a", {"class": "PropertyInformationCommonStyles__addressCopy--link"}).text
    # house type
    house = container.div.find("div", {"class": "QuickPropertyDetails__propertyType"}).text
    # number of bathrooms
    bath_num = container.div.find("div", {"class": "QuickPropertyDetails__iconCopy--WithBorder"}).text
    # number of bedrooms
    bed_num = container.div.find("div",{"class": "QuickPropertyDetails__iconCopy"}).text

    data.append((price, name_container, house, bath_num, bed_num))

print(data)
```

Your final output will look as follows:

```
[('€1,350,000', 'The Penthouse at Hanover Quay, 27 Hanover Dock, Grand Canal Dock, Dublin 2', 'Apartment for sale', '2', '3'), ('€450,000', '9 Na Ceithre Gaoithe Ring, Dungarvan, Co. Waterford', ' Detached House', '4', '5'), ('€390,000', 'Cave, Caherlistrane, Co. Galway', ' Detached House', '4', '5'), ('€720,000', '18 Hazelbrook Road, Terenure, Terenure, Dublin 6', ' Detached House', '3', '4'), ('€210,000', 'Carraig Abhainn, Ballisodare, Co. Sligo', 'Bungalow for sale', '1', '3'), ('€495,000', 'Campbell Court, Cairns Hill, Sligo, Co. Sligo', ' Detached House', '4', '4'), ('€125,000', '33 Leim An Bhradain, Gort Road, Ennis, Co. Clare', 'Apartment for sale', '2', '2'), ('€395,000', '1 Windermere Court, Bishopstown, Bishopstown, Co. Cork', ' End of Terrace House', '3', '4'), ('€349,000', '59 Dun Eoin, Ballinrea Road, Carrigaline, Co. Cork', ' Detached House', '3', '4'), ('€515,000', '2 Elm Walk, Classes Lake, Ovens, Co. Cork', ' Detached House', '5', '4'), ('€490,000', '9 Munster st., Phibsborough, Dublin 7', ' Terraced House', '2', '4'), ('€249,950', '47 Westfields, Clare Road, Ennis, Co. Clare', ' Detached House', '3', '4'), ('€435,000', '3 Castlelough Avenue, Loreto Road, Killarney, Co. Kerry', ' Detached House', '3', '4'), ('€620,000', 'Beaufort House, Knockacleva, Philipstown, Dunleer, Dunleer, Co. Louth', ' Detached House', '3', '5'), ('€550,000', "Flat 5, Saint Ann's Apartments, Donnybrook, Dublin 4", 'Apartment for sale', '2', '2'), ('€675,000', '3 Church Hill, Innishannon, Co. Cork', ' Detached House', '3', '5'), ('€495,000', 'River Lodge, The Rower, Inistioge, Co. Kilkenny', ' Detached House', '4', '4'), ('€325,000', 'Coolgarrane House, Coolgarrane, Thurles, Co. Tipperary', ' Detached House', '1', '4'), ('€399,950', 'No 14 Coopers Grange Old Quarter, Ballincollig, Co. Cork', ' Semi-Detached House', '3', '4')]
```

Comment: @AdrianKenneally, Dict is other option if you would prefer easy lookup. Here Key can be your link and the contents can be Values (stored as list). This allow you to classify site specific data under a key/value pair.